# Makefile - append to command

Tags: makefile, docker

I am writing a Makefile for my Docker app. I have `make start-image`, which starts the image with it's default command:

```
start-image:
  docker run name
```

I would like to have another command `make do_something` which would append the command that should be run within the docker container:

```
do_something:
  docker run name command args
```

How can I use the start-image command to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use a variable to store the common part of the commands**

```
RUNTOOL=docker run name

start-image:
     ${RUNTOOL}

do-something:
     ${RUNTOOL} command args
```

With this strategy, it is also possible to build the *RUNTOOL* variable out of smaller parts to accomodate for more complex tasks.

Answer (score 0):

```
start-image:
    docker run name $(ARGS)

do_something: ARGS=command args
do_something: start-image
```